# How to add an element to a windows form by code?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

The question says it all, I want to add a TableLayoutPanel to an existing windows Form, I've tried this:

```
public class Level {

    public TableLayoutPanel brickGrid;

    public Level(Form parent, int width, int height, int left, int top, int rows, int columns) {
        brickGrid = new TableLayoutPanel();

        //Code

        brickGrid.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.InsetDouble;

        //Code

        brickGrid.SetAutoScrollMargin(2, 2);

        brickGrid.BringToFront();

        parent.Controls.Add(brickGrid);
    }
}
```

But it seems not to work :/

EDIT:
It's not throwing any crashes, error, exception or similar, the grid just won't show up.

Here is an image of the output:
http://prntscr.com/9385e9

And here is the full Code:

```
namespace PingPong.Source {

public class Level {

    public TableLayoutPanel brickGrid;

    public Level(Form parent, int width, int height, int left, int top, int rows, int columns) {
        brickGrid = new TableLayoutPanel();

        brickGrid.Width = width;
        brickGrid.Height = height;

        brickGrid.Left = left;
        brickGrid.Top = top;

        brickGrid.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.InsetDouble;

        int originalRowCount = brickGrid.RowCount;
        int originalColumnCount = brickGrid.ColumnCount;

        float columnPercentage = 100f * columns / width;
        float rowPercentage = 100f * rows / height;

        int index = 0;
        while (index <= columns) {
            brickGrid.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, columnPercentage));
            index++;
        }

        index = 0;
        while (index <= rows) {
            brickGrid.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, rowPercentage));
            index++;
        }

        index = 0;
        while (index < originalRowCount) {
            brickGrid.RowStyles.RemoveAt(originalRowCount - index + 1);
            index++;
        }

        index = 0;
        while (index < originalColumnCount) {
            brickGrid.ColumnStyles.RemoveAt(originalColumnCount - index + 1);
            index++;
        }

        brickGrid.SetAutoScrollMargin(2, 2);

        brickGrid.BringToFront();

        parent.Controls.Add(brickGrid);

        brickGrid.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? are you getting a compile error or an exception? Or you cannot see the new element on the form?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want, it's not possible to know what the right answer to your question is. I will point out that in general, "panel" types in Winforms do not in and of themselves usually show anything; you need to add something to them for them to be visible. Maybe all you need to do is add a child to your `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I just can't see the element-----------------------------PeterDuniho: I've added some more details. the grid should be visible I suppose, because I've added Borders to the cells, and it has a background color too. Anyways I'll try it, how do I add a child to the grid? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this didn't work and you just don't see it? I setup a form called `frmMain` that contains a `Panel` called `panel1`. The following code, which I only tweaked to set the background color, showed me the `backGrid` control with a red background.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableLayoutPanel brickGrid = new TableLayoutPanel();
        brickGrid.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.InsetDouble;
        brickGrid.SetAutoScrollMargin(2, 2);
        brickGrid.BringToFront();
        brickGrid.BackColor = Color.Red;
        panel1.Controls.Add(brickGrid);
    }
```

Maybe you just need to set the backcolor to  see if it worked and possibly step through the code to make sure.

Comment: The problem was that I was using the Form instead of a Panel. Thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized what was wrong on here, thanks to @Brian Payne . The Problem was that I was adding the grid to the Form's controls, when I had to add it to the main Panel's ones. Thanks to everyone ^^